# Generate Alphanumber field and Increment

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

i have a **transaction form** in oracle apex within that form has a page item called **transactioncode**.

what i will like, is to generate  a alphanumeric code on page load for eg. AA110  which will  increment everytime they create a new transaction.

```
table: transactioncode, transactiondate, productcode, productname.
```

I have not  tried any sql or pl/sql or trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SEQUENCE and assign the sequence.nextval to the field transactioncode or define the field as IDENTITY if you are using 12.1 onwards. If your version is prior to 12.1, then you need a trigger to associate the sequence.

Example below will show you column c1 as identity, column c2 using sequence

```
SQL> create sequence my_example start with 1000 increment by 1 maxvalue    9999999999999999 ;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table my_test ( c1 NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY , c2 number default my_example.nextval , c3 varchar2(1) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_test ( c3 ) values ( 1 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from my_test ;

        C1         C2 C
---------- ---------- -
         1       1000 1
```

The following restrictions applied to IDENTITY fields

- One identity column per table.
- Identity columns must be numeric types, and can't be user-defined
  data types.
- Identity columns can't have a default clause.
- Identity columns are implicitly have NOT NULL and NOT DEFERRABLE constraints.
  They can't be explicitly alter to anything else. From the doc, "If an
  identity column is encrypted, then the encryption algorithm may be
  inferred. Oracle recommends that you use a strong encryption
  algorithm on identity columns."
- The CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT will not inherit the identity property on a column. This is true for several structural definitions. If you care about structure, you
  should always CREATE TABLE, then use INSERT INTO ... SELECT to
  populate it.